# Stopping "php-fpm" ( homebrew installation ) Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: homebrew, php

I have managed to successfully install PHP-FPM using homebrew.

I have even configured my nginx.conf to work. However, whenever I do in the terminal:

```
$: php-fpm
```

I get the error :

```
[24-Jul-2013 19:58:34] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[24-Jul-2013 19:58:34] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf'
[24-Jul-2013 19:58:34] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

However, my nginx is working fine.

Here is the nginx.conf according to running Yii.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  campusplugin;
        set $host_path "/var/www/campusplugin";

        root   $host_path;

        set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

        charset utf-8;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
        }


        #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        }


        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
            set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
             if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
             }

            root           /var/www/campusplugin;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
            
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }
```

I am also not able to `stop` the php-fpm. I need to stop it as I have modified the php.ini a little bit. What is the method to do it??

```
service php-fpm restart
-bash: service: command not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Even when I am typing : `php-fpm -v` I am getting :

```
php-fpm -v
PHP 5.3.15 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

However, it is showing the old php-fpm, as I had installed 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :

The method to do it was as follows :

**1. To checkout php-fpm, use :**

```
php-fpm php54-fpm
```

**2. To stop the service, we have to use Apple's SystemStarter, like so :**

```
SystemStarter php54-fpm restart
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you failed to understand? 1st or the second?

Comment: SystemStarter doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 65):

I used this guide for my set up:
https://web.archive.org/web/20161220083008/https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew

And this command to restart my php-fpm:

```
brew services restart php56
```

If you don't have brew services, try installing it like this:

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

---

In more modern versions, simply doing

```
brew services start php
brew services stop php
brew services restart php
```

would either start, stop or restart the php-fpm service.

Answer (score 4):

Apple says: ["The SystemStarter utility is deprecated."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/SystemStarter.8.html)

But I found another great solution:

1. Put this in ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/: https://github.com/tarnfeld/osx-stack/blob/master/LaunchDaemons/org.php-fpm.plist
2. Change paths in this plist file according to your paths (e.g. my php-fpm executable is in /usr/sbin instead of /usr/local/sbin)
3. Put the following in a new file in /usr/sbin/ or /usr/local/sbin/

.

```
/#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping php-fpm..."
launchctl unload -w /Users/<home-folder>/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.php-fpm.plist
echo "Starting php-fpm..."
launchctl load -w /Users/<home-folder>/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.php-fpm.plist
echo "php-fpm restarted"
exit 0
```

make sure that directory is in your $PATH

Now you can call 'php-restart' to restart php-fpm

(Thanks to [another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm))

Comment: `/Users/<home-folder>` could be replaced by `~`.  So `/Users/<home-folder>/Library`is the same as `~/Library`

Comment: Unload failed: 5: Input/output error

Answer (score 1):

If you use mac, You can checkout your php-fpm is running?

you can use this command:
php-fpm -t

Now, You can see the question! And how to resolve by this error info in
the command line!

Comment: This only tests the config file

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Mac OS X (tested on 13.x) in order to stop the php-fpm daemon and deregister it from launching at login or boot it's as simple as running this command:

```
brew services stop php
```